# Double jQuery entry in wordpress file

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have 2 jquery script tags on this [page](http://beta.fray.it/invite/) and I am trying to find where they are inserted from. I have located one which comes from header.php, but cannot find the second one. Is there a browser developer tool that could help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

A browser developer toolbar will not tell you what WordPress item is asking for another jQuery script.

Often plugins and themes will want to include their own version...and it can cause conflicts.

The version of jQuery installed with your wordpress version is 1.10.2, and "something" is calling jQuery 1.8.2.

You may want to try removing the reference to 1.8.2 from your theme file (header.php)

Comment: I thought so too, but on removing it I get many uncaught reference errors on other scripts saying jquery is not defined etc.

Comment: Managed to remove the default version of JQuery following this article http://goo.gl/0xIJ4

Answer (score 0):

Just try the following mini plugin:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Debug Scripts */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    var_dump( current_filter(), $GLOBALS['wp_filters'], $GLOBALS['wp_scripts'] );
}, 999 );
```

This will tell you

- The name of the current filter (`wp_enqueue_scripts`)
- All registered filters
- All registered scripts

Then search for your script, search for the callback and then search for the plugin or theme causing it. You got all the tools.

Comment: how should i run this? on its own file? and store it where?

Comment: What? That's a plugin that helps you debug. Zip it, upload it, activate it, start debugging...

Comment: Cannot find a script with that name. Maybe you mean "Plugin Debug Bar List Script & Style Dependencies"?

Comment: I'm talking about _the plugin I coded into my answer above_... omg.

Comment: wow...now I know what var_dump means! It's like needle in the hay in there...but thanks a lot anyway